# my flashplayer showing NaH:NaH in timeline, how can I fix it?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs4

I've added a script in my flash video players actionscript for when flash video ends it should goes to the first frame. Its working FINE! but theres a problem that an invalid "NaH:NaH" is showing after the video when it is goes to the first frame after finished playing.

This is happening after running the script(script for going to the first frame after video finished) to the existing action script..
I need to show the timeline as "00:00"

Can anyone plz modify the code and tell what is the issue behind the code...?

The script is given below

```
var listenerObject:Object = new Object();
listenerObject.complete = function(eventObject:Object):Void {
        gotoAndPlay(0);
};
flv.addEventListener("complete", listenerObject);
```

"flv" represents video playing area

Please Help Me

Thanks 
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're getting `NaN` which stands for 'Not a Number'. you need to make sure variables you are using in your mathematical calculations are, in fact, Numbers (not `null`, `undefined`, `Strings`, or other data types).